# Graphics driver for "PC Notebook M760S" for Win 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I am trying to format my aunts computer, maybe 5-6 years old. It is from a small Danish company Zepto. I think they buy laptops from no-name chinese manufacturers, and just put their label on them. On the back of it it says "PC Notebook M760S".

I have installed Windows 7 on it. And most seems fine. But there is something wrong with the graphics, eg the max resolution is very low. So I hope I can find some graphics driver for Windows 7 that can fix this.

I have been looking around. Even tried some of those shady universal driver tools, but they did not fix the problem.

Maybe someone can help.

This is the output, when using the Linux lshw tool:

```
karenzepto
    description: Computer
    product: M7x0S ()
    vendor: clevo
    version: Rev. A1
    serial: 12345678901234567
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=oem-specific frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=unknown power-on_password=disabled uuid=0090F58A-A094-0000-0000-000000000000
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: M7x0S
       vendor: clevo
       physical id: 0
       version: Bottom
       serial: SI96A-55
       slot: Bottom
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Phoenix Technologies LTD
          physical id: 0
          version: 6.00
          date: 03/26/2009
          size: 107KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Genuine Intel(R) CPU             585  @ 2.16GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 processor
          slot: uPGA 479M
          size: 2160MHz
          capacity: 3600MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc up arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 16KiB
             capacity: 16KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: burst internal write-back
     *-cache
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 7
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capabilities: burst internal write-back
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: e
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 3GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DRAM Synchronous
             physical id: 0
             slot: DIMM1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DRAM Synchronous
             physical id: 1
             slot: DIMM2
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 671MX
          vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-sis latency=32
          resources: irq:0 memory:d0000000-d7ffffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: AGP Port (virtual PCI-to-PCI bridge)
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master
             resources: ioport:9000(size=4096) memory:d8000000-d80fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter
                vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 10
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 66MHz
                capabilities: pm agp agp-3.0 vga_controller cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d8000000-d801ffff ioport:9000(size=128)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO]
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-ide:0
             description: IDE interface
             product: 5513 IDE Controller
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 2.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.5
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pata_sis latency=128
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:1080(size=16)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: USB 1.1 Controller
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 0f
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32 maxlatency=80
             resources: irq:20 memory:d8204000-d8204fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: USB 1.1 Controller
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 3.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.1
             version: 0f
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci_hcd latency=32 maxlatency=80
             resources: irq:21 memory:d8205000-d8205fff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: USB 2.0 Controller
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 3.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=32 maxlatency=80
             resources: irq:22 memory:d8206000-d8206fff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             logical name: eth0
             version: 02
             serial: 00:90:f5:8a:a0:94
             size: 10Mbit/s
             capacity: 100Mbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sis190 driverversion=1.4 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
             resources: irq:19 memory:d8407000-d840707f ioport:1000(size=128)
        *-ide:1
             description: IDE interface
             product: SATA Controller / IDE mode
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sata_sis latency=32
             resources: irq:17 ioport:10c8(size=8) ioport:10bc(size=4) ioport:10c0(size=8) ioport:10b8(size=4) ioport:10a0(size=16)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: PCI-to-PCI bridge
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=8192) memory:dc000000-dfffffff ioport:b8000000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: PCI-to-PCI bridge
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:d8100000-d81fffff ioport:b8200000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RT2790 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R PCIe
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 00
                serial: 00:15:af:e6:ba:89
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.5.0-17-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:16 memory:d8100000-d810ffff
        *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: FLASH memory
             product: ENE PCI Memory Stick Card Reader Controller
             vendor: ENE Technology Inc
             physical id: 9
             bus info: pci@0000:00:09.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=32 maxlatency=4 mingnt=1
             resources: memory:b8400200-b840027f
        *-generic
             description: SD Host controller
             product: ENE PCI SmartMedia / xD Card Reader Controller
             vendor: ENE Technology Inc
             physical id: 9.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:09.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=32 maxlatency=72 mingnt=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:b8400000-b84000ff
        *-memory:1
             description: FLASH memory
             product: ENE PCI Secure Digital / MMC Card Reader Controller
             vendor: ENE Technology Inc
             physical id: 9.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:09.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=72 mingnt=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:b8400100-b84001ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Azalia Audio Controller
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0 maxlatency=11 mingnt=52
             resources: irq:18 memory:d8200000-d8203fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: PCI-to-PCI bridge
             vendor: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:0
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: CDDVDW SN-S082H
             vendor: TSSTcorp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: SB01
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST9120823AS
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 3.AA
             serial: 5NJ04FZL
             size: 111GiB (120GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=b815720e
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 185f-a6be
                size: 98MiB
                capacity: 100MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2012-12-17 17:05:46 filesystem=ntfs label=Reserveret til systemet state=clean
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                serial: d41abcdf-0dd1-4e45-aef1-f2d9ad22143e
                size: 73GiB
                capacity: 73GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2012-12-23 18:40:35 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
           *-volume:2
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                size: 38GiB
                capacity: 38GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume:0
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 3814MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
              *-logicalvolume:1
                   description: Linux filesystem partition
                   physical id: 6
                   logical name: /dev/sda6
                   logical name: /
                   capacity: 34GiB
                   configuration: mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered state=mounted
  *-remoteaccess UNCLAIMED
       vendor: SiS
       physical id: 1
       capabilities: inbound
```

If someone can point me to a driver, or give me a hint on how to find it, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Did you verify the laptop was compatible with Windows 7 before installing? Have you installed all Windows Updates?

Comment: I don't know if it is compatible with Win 7. I don't know how I should have found out. I assume the industry will never go out and say that an old product of theirs is compatible with an OSthat did not exist when they sold it. I know that the laptop works plug and play with the newest versions of Ubuntu, if that is any help :)

Comment: Yes, all Windows 7 updates are installed.

Comment: Running the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20) is a good start. The trouble with some of the older "off brand" computers is the manufacturers don't update drivers for upgrade compatibility of their hardware.

Comment: Oh jesus, a SiS VGA controller! I haven't seen one of those since I was demolishing some decade old machines and ripping out their pci cards a few years back. I would suggest trying this one ftp://ftp.work.acer-euro.com/desktop/aspire_t136/vista/Drivers/SiS%20VGA%20driver%203.78.00.zip It's vista, but a lot of vista drivers work fine in 7. If this works, please let me know so I can upgrade to a full answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I somehow solved the problem, but I am not sure exactly, what did it.